# Ругается на serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Почему ругается на formNm.serialize()

```
<script>

 btnSubmit.onclick = function(){
 var formID = 'price_form';
 var formNm = $('#' + formID);
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: 'assets/ajax.php',
data: {
    formNm.serialize(),
    action:'payments_user',

 },
 success: function (data) {
 $('#message').html(data);
 setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#message').html(' ');
                    },5000);
                    location.reload();
 },

 error: function () {
 $('#message').html('Ошибка');
  setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#message').html(' ');
                    },5000);
 }
 });
 return false;
 };

</script>
```

Comment: "ругается" - какими словами?

Comment: Unexpected token .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы пропустили название поля в объекте для свойства `data`:

```
data: {
    values: formNm.serialize(),
    action:'payments_user',
},
```

А правильнее так:

```
btnSubmit.onclick = function(){
  var formID = 'price_form';
  var formNm = $('#' + formID);
  if (formNm.find("#action").length == 0) {
    formNm.append("<input type='hidden' name='action' id='action' />");
  }
  formNm.find("#action").val("payments_user");
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'assets/ajax.php',
    data: formNm.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
      ...
```

Comment: теперь в файл передает пустые значения

Comment: @Aslero в какой "файл"? Вы думаете мне видны мысли в Вашем мозгу?

Comment: assets/ajax.php

Comment: echo $_POST['id_user']; выдает пустое значение

Comment: @Aslero Вам не мешало бы задуматься над принятием ответов на Ваши вопросы. На 120 вопросов один принятый ответ - это должно быть рекорд.